# App kivy does not connect from the mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, kivy

Anyone know why when the application is installed on android it does not connect from the mysql database?

strange that when installing, the app does not request permission to access intenet, even if buildozer.spec is allowed.

buildozer.spec looks like this:

requirements = kivy, pymysql, python2

android.permissions = INTERNET

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
import pymysql.cursors


db = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", password="xxxxx", 
database="db_financ)
cur = db.cursor() 

# select database
cur.execute("SELECT desc_desp, valor FROM despesa WHERE id_despesa <> 0")
row=cur.fetchall()


layout = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))


for i in row:
    btn = Button(text=i[0] + "\nR$ " + str(i[1]), size_hint_y=None, height=150)
    layout.add_widget(btn)


root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
root.add_widget(layout)

runTouchApp(root)
```

tks for help

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but it is because localhost (‘127.0.0.1’) is your computers internal IP address. So it would only work on your machine. You would need to change “host” to your computers internal IP address. You can figure out your computers internal IP address on windows by typing in the command line “IP CONFIG”. That will display your computers internal IP address. I do not know what the command arg is on OX or LINUX, but it is something similar.